# How to add a additional property in the overview tab of the bit dev mdx documentation for the components?

Tags: react-native, mdx, bit, bit.dev

We have a bit component published through a private scope. We want to add some additional properties along with the default properties that are being displayed in overview portion of the component documentation. I have searched through all of the bit documentation, but still not sure whether we can do this.

Please find the below screenshot. Name, Type , default, Description along with that I want to add additional field. Can anyone please help.

[image]